# Array of legends for charts in highcharts-export-server

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am working on [highcharts-export-server](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server) which currently does not support [formatter functions](https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/issues/122) as it expects the chart configuration in plain JSON format and not JavaScript object.

I need customized values for chart's legends and I couldn't find [any config](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend) to supply legends as array of formatted strings.

Is it be possible to supply those legends as array of formatted strings which can be passed as plain JSON? If it can also support color of series, that would be awesome.

Thank you in advance.

I could not ask this question or raise a new issue in the `node-export-server` repo because it only accepts issue [for a bug](https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/issues/new). And I think this could be a feature request(In that case, I will raise it to Highcharts later).

**Edit:** Solution for passing simple formatters(without library or called functions) -

A [stringified JS Object](https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/issues/122#issuecomment-408819924) under `instr` key works for simple formatter functions with `allowCodeExecution` flag in config, shown below. Also in [sample](https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/blob/643aece3857ce4bc2698e20384192f06442aede7/samples/module/module_straight_inject.js#L14).

```
{
  instr: stringifyObject(chartConfig), // https://gist.github.com/cowboy/3749767
  allowCodeExecution: true, // to support formatter functions in chart config
  ... other configs
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to add [formatting](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting) in [legend.labelFormat](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.labelFormat) as HTML, export server accepts such a solution you can test the following config at [new version of export server](https://export-dev.highcharts.com/).

```
{
    "xAxis": {
        "categories": [
            "Jan",
            "Feb",
            "Mar",
            "Apr",
            "May",
            "Jun",
            "Jul",
            "Aug",
            "Sep",
            "Oct",
            "Nov",
            "Dec"
        ]
    },
    "series": [
        {
            "data": [1,3,2,4],
            "type": "line"
        },
        {
            "data": [5,3,4,2],
            "type":"line"
        }
    ],
    "legend": {
      "margin": 140,
      "useHTML": true,
      "labelFormat": "<b>test</b>"
    }
}
```

To feature request to add this option you can report it in the GitHub issue and it will be assigned with label enhancement.

Comment: You are correct, the normal [labelFormat](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.labelFormat) works fine. But in my case, because of logical conditions, [labelFormatter](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.labelFormatter) would be needed, similar [to this](https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/issues/346) but for legends. I am also looking at the usage of `allowCodeExecution` config flag, but haven't found any success yet. Will update after any progress.

Comment: Also, haven't succeeded with string version of [config instr](https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/blob/643aece3857ce4bc2698e20384192f06442aede7/samples/module/module_straight_inject.js#L14). Still checking on that approach.

Comment: In our new export server version `allowCodeExecution` will work, in the public server, it's turned off to prevent JS injection.